# Proxy for an HTTP request WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wonder if it is possible to send an HTTP request throuht WSO2 ESB. I have an integration with a system that consist only in invoking an URL... it would be like a kind of redirection.

Can I do that in WSO2 ESB?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below links will be help you to find a solution to your question.

1. http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/03/handling-httpget-request-invoking-external-web-service-wso2-esb
2. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Handling+HTTP-get+Requests+from+WSO2+ESB+and+Calling+an+External+Web+Service

Answer (score 1):

I have found this link about restfull services in WSO2 ESB:

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/10/implementing-restful-services-wso2-esb

I think this is a better way to handle http requests & responses in wso2 esb, rather than the way they are treated in the links you provide. What do you think about that?